# How do I add a custom marker to the following Google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new with Google maps and I like this setup I found on codepen and would like base my own project on it but change the styles, however it does not have markers for addresses which I'd like to be able to add. I also want my marker to be a custom png file. I can understand that the map is centered for a specific lat and lng but I'd like to keep a center value and add two or more addresses near by with custom markers. How would I go about doing that?

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.946672,-82.482866),
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    styles: styleArray
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Here's the link to the codepen project:

http://codepen.io/JonDCarey/pen/ncJoe

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marker API goes as followed:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: LatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
});
```

See your updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPOzvZ

Now custom PNG's are really easy to - just have to change the marker icon, e.g.:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: LatLng,
     map: map,
     title: 'Hello World!',
          icon: '<URL TO NEW ICON>'
     });
 });
```

Here is an example in CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPgKZm

The last is address translation - that's a bit more complex but here is a quick example:

```
var MarkerFromAddress = function(address) {
    geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });

        // I also can center the map here:
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
    });
  };

  MarkerFromAddress("1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View");
```

CodePen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJxYZM

Hope that helps

Comment: at first my question kept getting negative points and as a newbie I really appreciate you answering my question and putting in the time to explain it so clearly. You're absolutely wonderful!